# Scraping Yahoo Finance Balance Sheet with Python

Tags: python, regex, web-scraping, beautifulsoup, python-requests

My question is a follow-up question to one asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35439105/scrape-yahoo-finance-income-statement-with-python).

The function:

> periodic_figure_values()

seems to work fine except in the case where the name of a line item being searched appears twice.  The specific case I am referring to is trying to get data for "Long Term Debt".  The function in the link above will return the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 31, in <module>
    LongTermDebt=(periodic_figure_values(soup, "Long Term Debt"))
  File "test.py", line 21, in periodic_figure_values
    value = int(str_value)
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'Short/Current Long Term Debt'
```

because it seems to get tripped up on "Short/Current Long Term Debt".  You see, the page has both "Short/Current Long Term Debt" and "Long Term Debt".  You can see an example of the source page using Apple's balance sheet [here](https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=AAPL&annual).

I'm trying to find a way for the function to return data for "Long Term Debt" without getting tripped up on "Short/Current Long Term Debt".

Here is the function and an example that fetches "Cash and Cash Equivalents", which works fine, and "Long Term Debt", which does not work:

```
import requests, bs4, re

def periodic_figure_values(soup, yahoo_figure):
    values = []
    pattern = re.compile(yahoo_figure)
    title = soup.find("strong", text=pattern)    # works for the figures printed in bold
    if title:
        row = title.parent.parent
    else:
        title = soup.find("td", text=pattern)    # works for any other available figure
        if title:
            row = title.parent
        else:
            sys.exit("Invalid figure '" + yahoo_figure + "' passed.")
    cells = row.find_all("td")[1:]    # exclude the <td> with figure name
    for cell in cells:
        if cell.text.strip() != yahoo_figure:    # needed because some figures are indented
            str_value = cell.text.strip().replace(",", "").replace("(", "-").replace(")", "")
            if str_value == "-":
                str_value = 0
            value = int(str_value)
            values.append(value)
    return values

res = requests.get('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=AAPL')
res.raise_for_status
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
Cash=(periodic_figure_values(soup, "Cash And Cash Equivalents"))
print(Cash)
LongTermDebt=(periodic_figure_values(soup, "Long Term Debt"))
print(LongTermDebt)
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest would be to use a **`try/except`** combination using the raised `ValueError`:

```
import requests, bs4, re

def periodic_figure_values(soup, yahoo_figure):
    values = []
    pattern = re.compile(yahoo_figure)
    title = soup.find("strong", text=pattern)    # works for the figures printed in bold
    if title:
        row = title.parent.parent
    else:
        title = soup.find("td", text=pattern)    # works for any other available figure
        if title:
            row = title.parent
        else:
            sys.exit("Invalid figure '" + yahoo_figure + "' passed.")
    cells = row.find_all("td")[1:]    # exclude the <td> with figure name
    for cell in cells:
        if cell.text.strip() != yahoo_figure:    # needed because some figures are indented
            str_value = cell.text.strip().replace(",", "").replace("(", "-").replace(")", "")
            if str_value == "-":
                str_value = 0
### from here
            try:
                value = int(str_value)
                values.append(value)
            except ValueError:
                continue
### to here
    return values

res = requests.get('https://ca.finance.yahoo.com/q/bs?s=AAPL')
res.raise_for_status
soup = bs4.BeautifulSoup(res.text, 'html.parser')
Cash=(periodic_figure_values(soup, "Cash And Cash Equivalents"))
print(Cash)
LongTermDebt=(periodic_figure_values(soup, "Long Term Debt"))
print(LongTermDebt)
```

This one prints out your numbers quite fine.
Note, that you do not really need the `re` module in this situation here as you're checking for literals only (no wildcards, no boundaries), etc.

Comment: I'm trying to find a way for the function to return data for "Long Term Debt" without getting tripped up on "Short/Current Long Term Debt".

Answer (score 0):

You could change the function so that it accepts a regular expression instead of a plain string. Then you can search for `^Long Term Debt` to make sure there's no text before that. All you need to do is to change

```
if cell.text.strip() != yahoo_figure:
```

to

```
if not re.match(yahoo_figure, cell.text.strip()):
```